# Unable to pass json value in jmeter POST request

Tags: jmeter

I have 2 http requests that return different json responses. Used the JSON Path PostProcessor to retrieve the values (Value A and Value B) from the 2 json responses. When i tried to pass the values A and B in the request body of another http request, only value B is passed. 
http://screencast.com/t/Y3e9pZe2om5
http://screencast.com/t/TfUwM2kKqE

Comment: Can you double check your request

Comment: Where is you request? Where are you passing the group id? Check this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z2S-AxLfg-0) to check passing parameters between requests.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to build a composite variable like:

- you have `${A}` variable with the value of `foo`
- you have `${B}` variable with the value of `bar`
- you need to build `${AB}` variable

This can be done using __V() function like:

```
${__V(A${B})}
```

See [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables) article for more detailed information

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ppl. Moving the Json Path PostProcessor inside the http sampler request solved the issue.